# i want show div result when i clicked the asp button with css3

Tags: html, css

I want show div result when i clicked the asp button with css3  with slow motion please any one can help me.

```
<div id="showdivslowly" runat="server" style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:Blue ;display:none" >Welcome</div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will almost certainly be best done client side through an [Ajax call](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) to the server to fetch the result and append it to a hidden div which you animate either using [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) or by using the [jQuery animation methods like fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/). As the CSS display property is [not animatable using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties), you would either need to use the [opacity property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) (which will [not be fully supported cross-browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity), albeit probably sufficiently supported for most purposes and only the animation would be affected rather than the core functionality) or by using the jQuery methods.

If you handle the click event on the server side then the browser will complete a full page-postback, you can append the div using your server side code, and then use either a CSS3 transition or JavaScript to complete the animation client side.

For a code sample-

```
.result {
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;    }

.result.hidden {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;    
}

.result.shown {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```